# EVM bytecode instrumentation

Tags: evm, bytecode, monitoring

How can I instrument the EVM bytecode for runtime monitoring?
Is there any technique or implementation for that?

Comment: we aren't using these words like "instrumentation" here, please translate what you mean by that

Comment: also define: `monitoring`

Comment: I want to do concolic testing for EVM bytecode. According to what I understand about a concolic testing, we have to instrument the code before analyzing it. So,  I use the word instrumentation. And for monitoring I meant concolic testing based on the instrumented code and monitor for existing vulnerabilities. I would be glad to correct me If I am wrong about this concept .@Nulik

Comment: I have been working with assembly language for years, and this is the first time I hear about conocolic testing or instrumentation. I can say for sure that nobody does this. So you better write a specific request on what do you want to do.

Comment: tell your teacher that theory is different from practice

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is something that will create an intermediate representation (IR) between Solidity and EVM bytecode, and which will act as a high-level assembly equivalent which you can instrument, rather than instrumenting the EVM bytecode itself. (There are a few common tools for doing this in the wider world, such as LLVM which is used in C instrumentation.)

I'm not sure what is commonly used in the Ethereum ecosystem, but there are several papers detailing techniques. See, for example: [SIF: A Framework for Solidity Contract Instrumentation and Analysis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.01659.pdf)

**Edit:**

Actually it looks like a tool called [Zeus](https://www.ndss-symposium.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/ndss2018_09-1_Kalra_paper.pdf) will now create LLVM bitcode from Solidity, so that might be a place to start.

Comment: That is really helpful and similar to the work done in C. But, what if I want to instrument the bytecode itself, something like binary or bytecode instrumentation in C? Is there any tool for that? @Richard Horrocks

Comment: @richard Horrocks, please explain what you mean by "you can instrument, rather than instrumenting the EVM bytecode itself". I don't know what is instrument and what is instrumentation. Please define these words without using them in the defnition. This paper "ContractFuzzer: Fuzzing Smart Contracts for Vulnerability Detection" uses the "instrument" and "instrumentation" terms witout defining them.